# how to connect two intervals?

Tags: python, math, intervals

```
wells = [
    [
        [0, 0.4, 'pop'],
        [0.4, 1.2, 'sup'],
        [1.2, 2.4, 'gal'],
        [2.4, 3.2, 'grav40'],
        [3.2, 4, 'buz']
    ],
    [
        [0, 0.4, 'pop'],
        [0.4, 0.8, 'sup'],
        [0.8, 2.4, 'gal'],
        [2.4, 3.6, 'grav30'],
        [3.6, 4.4, 'buz']
    ]
]
```

Lists in the `wells` lists have the following format - **[interval from, interval to, interval description]**

We need to connect the 'intervals to' between the first and second list. This can be done using the same interval description.

Then we will get this result:

```
0.4 connects to 0.4
1.2 connects to 0.8
2.4 connects to 2.4
4 connects to 4.4
```

But since the text content of the following elements has the same description ('buz' = 'buz'), we need to get the following result:

```
0.4 connects to 0.4
1.2 connects to 0.8
2.4 connects to 2.4
3.2 connects to 3.6
4 connects to 4.4
```

i tried this code:

```
wells = [
    [
        [0, 0.4, 'pop'],
        [0.4, 1.2, 'sup'],
        [1.2, 2.4, 'gal'],
        [2.4, 3.2, 'grav40'],
        [3.2, 4, 'buz']
    ],
    [
        [0, 0.4, 'pop'],
        [0.4, 0.8, 'sup'],
        [0.8, 2.4, 'gal'],
        [2.4, 3.6, 'grav30'],
        [3.6, 4.4, 'buz']
    ]
]

def find_matching_points_all(list1, list2):
    matching_points = []

    for point1 in list1:
        for point2 in list2:
            if point1[2] == point2[2]:
                matching_points.append((point1[1], point2[1]))

                break
            
        return matching_points

matching_points = find_matching_points_all(wells[0], wells[1])

for pair in matching_points:
    print(f"{pair[0]} connects with {pair[1]}")
print()
```

**connections in the picture:**

[image]

Comment: First comment: it looks to me like your `return` is indented one level too many.

Comment: Second comment: Are you saying that, although 'grav30' and 'grav40' don't match, you want "3.2 connects to 3.6" because the list IMMEDIATELY after it has matching descriptions? If so, do you have any ideas about how you could change the body of the for loop in your function to achieve that?

Comment: @Joe, yes, but I have no ideas. I got an answer, but it's a completely different code. I need to add this condition to my code

Comment: If you add enumerate, as in `for i1, point1 in enumerate(list1)` (and similarly for list2), then in addition to checking point1[2]==point2[2], you could add `or (i1<len(list1)-1 and i2<len(list2)-1 and list1[i1+1][2]==list2[i2+1][2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to reshape your data to simplify the problem, now you have intervals, but you can express each interval as two data points - top of the layer and bottom of the layer, matching data expressed in this form will be just a dictionary lookup.

```py
wells = [
    [
        [0, 0.4, 'pop'],
        [0.4, 1.2, 'sup'],
        [1.2, 2.4, 'gal'],
        [2.4, 3.2, 'grav40'],
        [3.2, 4, 'buz']
    ],
    [
        [0, 0.4, 'pop'],
        [0.4, 0.8, 'sup'],
        [0.8, 2.4, 'gal'],
        [2.4, 3.6, 'grav30'],
        [3.6, 4.4, 'buz']
    ]
]

KEY_TOP = 0
KEY_BOTTOM = 1

def reshape(well):
    d = dict()
    for top, bottom, descr in well:
        d[(descr, KEY_TOP)] = top
        d[(descr, KEY_BOTTOM)] = bottom
    return d

well1 = reshape(wells[0])
well2 = reshape(wells[1])
keys = set(well1.keys()).intersection(well2.keys())
matching_points = [(well1[key], well2[key]) for key in keys]
matching_points.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])
```

After that all you need to do is deduplicate resulting `matching_points`

This will not work if `descr` is not unique within the well, in that case you need to use more sophisticated matching like finding all possible candidates and choosing the closest one.